# Why does getting a manifest of a Trait with a higher kinded type does not work?

Tags: scala

Can anybody explain me, why the following code does not work and what can i do to make it work?

Scala version is 2.10.4

```
scala> trait A[T[_]]
defined trait A

scala> trait B[T]
defined trait B

scala> manifest[A[B]]
<console>:10: error: erroneous or inaccessible type
manifest[A[B]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Manifest` has a lot of limitations, and for this reason it has been deprecated in favor of `TypeTag`.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
trait A[T[_]]
trait B[T]
typeTag[A[B]] // reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A[B]] = TypeTag[A[B]]
```

---

That said, if you still want to use a `Manifest`, you'll have to use it's weaker cousin `ClassManifest`, as it can represent higher-order kinds, since it does not require the full type information to be specified.

So you should be able to do

```
classManifest[A[B]]
```

right? Well, not quite. Here's the error you get in Scala 2.11.2

> kinds of the type arguments (B) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type T). B's type parameters do not match type T's expected parameters:
>   trait B has one type parameter, but type T has none

The compiler is getting confuses as `B` doesn't appear to have the right "shape". Mmm ok, scalac, trust me, it really has the right shape. Let's spoon-feed you...

```
classManifest[A[({type l[T] = B[T]})#l]]
// ClassManifest[A[[T]B[T]]] = A[<?>]
```

And that's scalac's broken type inference among different higher-kinds, in all its splendor.

Comment: TypeTag's certainly work in this case but Array's are tricky. Any chance you know how to detect whether or not the captured argument is an Array? Specifically: `typeTag[A[Array]].tpe.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head <:< typeOf[Array[_]]` returns false. But the same phrase on `B[Array[Int]]` is true. Any ideas?